# Laravel elqouent multiple whereraw bindings

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

```
$food = Food::whereRaw('fruit = "?"', [$this->fruit])
    ->whereRaw('vegetable = "?"', [$this->vegetable])
    ->get();
```

Running this returns:

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number (SQL: select * from foods where fruit = "apple" and vegetable = "cabbage" and foods.deleted_at is null
```

This query is valid and runs fine so why does it return the error?

Comment: I linked to an answer that applies to your code, even though the answer is about SQLite. In this case, the answer is the same for any brand of SQL database.